# Using Opacity for highlighted chart does not work

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid standalone charts to create a pie chart. Rather than define a fixed colour for the highlight, I want to use opacity.
I tried setting the following in the series, but this did not work...

```
        highlightStyle: {
          fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        },
```

This just makes the segment black as I hover over it. It does not take account of the opacity.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did try the same in the fiddle and i am able to get grey color when hovering over the pie chart. if I increase the opacity the color goes to black and decreasing the opacity turns the color to white. so i guess it is working as expected.

if this doesn't answer your question you can update the fiddle so others can fix  the problem much better.

I am also using the same property while initializing the chart.

```
    highlightStyle: {
      fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
    },
```

check out this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/c5g9jyxp/